# How can I be sure that libssl-dev includes headers from libssl 0.9.8 instead of libssl 1.0?

Tags: c++, openssl, ubuntu-12.04

I'm migrating a development environment from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 12.04. An issue is that lib openssl has been upgraded from version  0.9.8 to 1.xxx.

I got a lot of useful tips from other questions but now I'm not sure my final version is really correct or not.

I am using an SDK which has the following content

- some dynamic libraries which requires explicitly the version 0.9.8 of the library (else I get an error message at runtime)
- some headers requiring include of openssl/x509.h and openssl/evp.h

What I did:

- apt-get install libssl-dev (created the headers under /usr/include/openssl/)
- apt-get install libssl0.9.8 (to have this version of the library).

**==> Everything seems to work just fine.**

**BUT** I am afraid that the includes I got through the libssl-dev are the ones of the 1.0 versions and they could mess up with my code running with the 0.9.8 version.

Is my current environment correct or should I do something else (like somehow getting the headers of the 0.9.8 version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libssl-dev` includes the 1.0 header files, there are no Ubuntu-provided development packages for 0.9.8. If I had to use 0.9.8, I'd probably just compile it myself and install to `/usr/local`.

Comment: you mean something like:
1 - Get the 0.9.8 includes ([link]from http://www.openssl.org/source/) an put them into /usr/local/include/
2 - Get the library from apt-get install listssl0.9.8.

Correct>?

Comment: @Marc: Likely to work, but what I actually meant was to just download the source and do what the INSTALL file inside the package says, you'll end up with binary libs in /usr/local/lib that you can link to.